# How can I mount an EF-M lens on an EF-S camera?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, canon-m

How can I mount an EF-M lens (22mm, for example) on my Canon Rebel T4i EOS EF-S?

Comment: Quite close to a duplicate of [What's the difference between Canon EF-S and EF-M?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/whats-the-difference-between-canon-ef-s-and-ef-m); in particular see the last paragraph of [drfrogsplat's answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/29740/11371).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Canon EF-S and EF-M?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/whats-the-difference-between-canon-ef-s-and-ef-m)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot mount an EF-M Lens on a standard DSLR or at least it won't work the way you want it to.

The EF-M lenses are designed to sit closer to the sensor than on a DLSR. There is no way to get the EF-M lens closer to a DSLR sensor because the mirror is in the way.

You can however, put a DSLR lens on the EOS-M camera with what is essentially a spacer to keep the lens further from the EOS-M sensor (the distance it would be if used on a DSLR).

Answer (score 4):

Strangely enough, you CAN fit an EF-M lens to an EF mount camera. It's just a very silly thing to want to do. Here's [what happened](https://web.archive.org/web/20180324200618/http://www.everyothershot.com/yes-you-can-use-an-ef-m-lens-on-an-ef-body-sort-of/) when I tried it.

Comment: That's a great blog post, but I'm afraid that this isn't a great answer. Here, as on all Stack Exchange sites, we discourage "link only" answers because when (not if) the link eventually breaks, the answer becomes useless. Could you add a short summary of your post to this answer? It might be something like: "I connected an EF-M lens to an EF-mount camera using ____, and although it was fun, it didn't really work because ____ and ____. The full in-depth account is on my blog at ____."

Answer (score 2):

If an adapter existed, on EF/EF-S, the lens would sit farther in front of the camera body than it's designed to, and this would be like using macro extension tubes: you'd lose the ability to focus to infinity with the lens, and it would only be good for photographing close subjects. Which is why such an adapter doesn't exist.

Comment: But what if I got fisheye lens of 7.5 that all manual (apture and focuse). Couldn't it work well enough?
Lens that are so wide don't need too much focuse.

Comment: "But what if I got fisheye lens of 7.5 that all manual (apture and focuse). Couldn't it work well enough? Lens that are so wide don't need too much focus" This is what I was thinking
The 7artisans 7.5mm for ef-m mount. Sounds like from the previous post link on someones experience it might be no infinity, he also warns electronic lens will be locked at minimum (not maximum) aperture so f/22. But the 7artisans in manual aperture and manual focus. And it's super wide.... So 14mm on a crop body, and a little less extreme...sounds good to me?

Comment: @DoronTshuva. Sorry for the late reply :), but no that won't make any difference. With roughly 2cm distance difference it would mean something more like not being able to focus past 4cm.